# Android Navigation Component + Login Flow + Nested BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-bottom-nav-view, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm struggle building a Navigation, like on the image below, with the Android Navigation Component.

I need a "Login Flow", check if the user is logged in and then navigate to the main part of the app (also clearing the backstack). The main part contains a BottomNavigationView with three tabs. But if I click on a settings icon on the toolbar, I also want to display a fullscreen SettingsFragment.

Did I need two NavHostFragments with separate navigation graphs? If yes, how can I combine them and also have a proper backNavigation?

Any ideas how realize a navigation like this with the android navigation components?

[image]

Comment: Have you had any idea about it? I am trying to do it with mainFragment as start destination, here I validate session active, if not, navigate to login, with popUp="nav_graph" and popUpToInclusive="false" and seems to work fine, using your provided current navigation graph flow. With destination listener I'm hiding toolbar and bootm navigation when detects loginFragment . I'm using version 2.0.0-rc02

Comment: Curious how did you get the bottomnavview in the fragment working with nav graph ?

Comment: @duskandawn did it work for you? I am having problems implementing it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you can check [Conditional Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional)

Second of all, you can do it with only one `nav_graph`. But you need only one `Activity` for this. After that, you can check in it like this:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
         if(destination.id == R.id.mainFragment){
             if(userIsLoggedIn()){
              //start LoginFragment
              //hide bottom navigation
             }else{
                //show bottom navigation
             }
          } 
        }
```

But your starter fragment should be `MainFragment` and not `LoginFragment`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
navController.setGraph(R.navigation.xxxx)
```

inside some `navController`.

[image: the setGraph]