# Android Navigation component popUpTo taking back to popped up fragment

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

Please do not mark this as duplicate, I have read these SO question already but still, it is not working
[navigation component popUpTo bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750264/navigation-component-popupto-bug)
[Android navigation component popUpTo behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744831/android-navigation-component-popupto-behaviour)
[Android Navigation Component + Login Flow + Nested BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470088/android-navigation-component-login-flow-nested-bottomnavigationview)

I am using

```
def nav_version = "2.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

Scenario: Here is my app graph
[image]

And this is my navigation code:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
        android:name="com.view.SplashFragment"
        android:label="SplashFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_mainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
```

When I press back button when I am on `MainFragment` or `LoginFragment` I am still able to navigate back to splashFragment. I have `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive` tags present already. I want my app not to navigate back to `splashFragment`

Comment: Why do you have a splash fragment as the start destination of your graph? That is specifically not following the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) nor the [guide to Conditional Navigation for login](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This is just a test POC to figure out how these navigation tags works, that's the reason I did not follow the guides you mention. The idea here is just to test a few things quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong id in your `popUpTo`

As per the [popUpTo guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop):

> `app:popUpTo` tells the Navigation library to pop some destinations off of the back stack as part of the call to `navigate()`. The attribute value is the ID of the most recent destination that should remain on the stack.
>
> You can also include `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` to indicate that the destination specified in `app:popUpTo` should also be removed from the back stack.

The `popUpTo` should point to the destination that is already on the back stack that you want to pop off the back stack. Therefore if you want to pop everything *up to* the `splashFragment`, you should use `app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"`. If you want to pop everything *up to and including* the `splashFragment`, then you should use `app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
    android:name="com.view.SplashFragment"
    android:label="SplashFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_loginFragment"
        app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_mainFragment"
        app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>
```